# Problem about variation method in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, variational-calculus

Firstly,I'm sorry that I'm not a native English speaker and I'm not very familiar with how to show formulas on website.

I have made some efforts.But I still can't figure out why the result is wrong. Here is my question below.

We have
$$\delta S=\frac{1}{T} \delta U+\frac{p}{T} \delta V,\delta^{2} S=\delta\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) \delta U+\delta\left(\frac{P}{T}\right) \delta V 
 (1)$$
$$\delta U=T \delta S-P \delta V,\delta^{2} U=\delta T \delta S-\delta P \delta V(2)$$
(The letter part of (1)(2) is just a middle procedure, we can choose any 2 variables as independent variables,eg. T,V)

Meanwhile,we noticed that $\delta^{2} S=-\frac{\delta^{2} U}{T}(3)$(All above can be proved by trivial calculation)
Now,according to the linearity of variational-calculus,we believe that$$\delta^{2} U=\delta T \delta S-\delta P \delta V+T \delta^{2} S-P \delta^{2} V(4)$$
$$\delta^{2} S=\delta\left(\frac{1}{T}\right) \delta U+\delta(\frac{P}{T}) \delta V+\frac{1}{T} \delta^{2} U+\frac{P}{T} \delta^{2} V(5)$$
Compare the results with $(1)(2)$, we can get $\delta^{2} S=\frac{P}{T} \delta^{2} V, \delta^{2} U=-P \delta^{2} V(6)$.

Therefore, we get $\delta^{2} S=-\frac{\delta^{2} U}{T}$, which is consistent with $(3)$.

It seems like our belief above is right. However, after serious derivation process, we find that $\delta^2 V=-\frac{1}{P}\delta^2U$. But in $(6)$, we get $\delta^2 V=\frac{1}{P}\delta^2U$! What's wrong above?

Here are more details in the picture:
[image: Problem]

Comment: Here is a guide on Latex from [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1). I would suggest using it. Regarding your question. What are you trying to proove?Also, from my memory, these games with variations in thermodynamics are often about distinction of what is kept fixed during the differentiation. Be explicit about it. For example, in your first equation you are working with $S=S\left(U,\,V\right)$ whilst in the second equation, suddenly, you vary $T,\,U,\,P,\,V$? I don't think you have that many degrees of freedom

Comment: e.g. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/therid.html. Note the diligence with noting what is kept constant.

Comment: Actually, It seems like that the linearity of variational-calculus here is inapplicable. And I wonder why it's so.